# How to place DIVs under each other

Tags: html, css

I just want to place one div below the other, without using br in html or filling the first line.

```css
 div.left {
     float: left;
     width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
 }
 
 div.right {
    float:left;
     width: 200px;
     height:200px;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Content</div>
<div class="right">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behaviour. Remove `float: left` from the rules.

```css
div.left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

div.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Content</div>
<div class="right">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer in another thread. it needs clear: left; in the second css div.

```css
 div.left {
     float: left;
     width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
 }
 
 div.right {
    float:left;
    clear: left;
     width: 200px;
     height:200px;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Content</div>
<div class="right">Content</div>
```

Comment: But why.... you just need to remove the `float: left;`.... like in the answer __that you accepted__???

Answer (score 0):

A div is a so called *block element*, which means that by default, it will always take the full available width and causes the following elements to be rendered below it.

`float: left` overrides this behaviour and causes the follwing elements to be rendered next to it (to the right in the case of float: left).

So the solution to you problem is to remove the `float:left` from your CSS.